# Link to script in only one Jinja template

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have one line of code that I would like to add to the head of my Jinja2 HTML page. I could easily add it as any other meta tags or etc, but I need this code in only one page, therefore no reasons to keep it in the site's header.

I tried to pass it as a string to `render_template`, but it didn't appear in the final render.

```
@app.route('/page')
def page():
    str = "<script src='https://site.xy/api.js'></script>"

    return render_template('page.html', script_string = str)
```

`page.html`:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{{script_string}}
{% block content %}
```

I also tried to do it in the layout file with blocks, but it failed too.

```
{% block js %}<script src='https://site.xy/api.js'></script>{% endblock %}
```

How can I add a script tag to the head of `page.html` without adding it to any other pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the block, but leave it empty by default, and set it in `page.html`.

`layout.html`:

```
<head>
    {% block head_js %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

`page.html`:

```
{% block head_js %}<script src='https://example.com/api.js'></script>{% endblock %}
```